# how to solve "No keyword with name 'Append To List' found." error in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to get all the text from a class or xpath, iterate over it and put it in a list.

Tried below code but keep getting this error:

> No keyword with name 'Append To List' found.

```
${xpath}=    Set Variable    //label[@class='required']
${count}=    Get Element Count    ${xpath}
${names}=    Create List
:FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1    ${count} + 1
\    ${name}=    Get Text    xpath=(${xpath})[${i}]
\    Append To List    ${names}    ${name}
\    Log To Console  ${names}
```

Other solution that i tried .getting same error for the below code as well.

```
 @{locators}=   Get Webelements   ${requiredDocuments}
 @{result}=   Create List
 : FOR    ${locator}    IN    @{locators}
 \    ${name}=    Get Text    ${locator}
 \    Log     ${name}
 \    Append To List   ${result}    ${name}
 Log   ${result}
```

Comment: I've removed the python tag from the question as I do not see anything that relates to it, except for the fact that robotframework is written in python. If you're not asking about python code or things directly relating to the python language, please don't add the tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import the standard library `Collections` in order to use the keyword `Append To List`. To [import the library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#importing-libraries), declare it in the settings of your test case, for example like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this with the BuiltIn Library.  Turns out, I had only once space between the command and the keyword.  Once I added two spaces, my keyword was recognized.  It doesn't look like that is your problem but it resolves this error and for me, spacing was my problem.